# Iterating over a JSON array

Tags: arrays, json, python-3.x, for-loop, nested-loops

I have the following JSON array;

```
"json_array": [
    {
        "key": "k1",
        "value": "v1"
    },
    {
        "key": "k2",
        "value": "v2"
    }
]
```

Need to list values as v1,v2.

Currently, I am able to list the keys and values separately as follows, but as a whole, not separately:

k1:v1
k2:v2

or

k1
k2

or

v1
v2

I was trying to get something like:
v1,v2 but I'm not sure how to go about the iteration, like if I just need to print one value either v1 or v2. If someone could help me with the logic in Python 3, that would be really great.

Edited code:

```
json_array = [
    [
        {
            "key": "k1",
            "value": "v1"
        },
        {
            "key": "k1",
            "value": "v2"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "key": "k1",
            "value": "v3"
        },
        {
            "key": "k2",
            "value": "v4"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "key": "k2",
            "value": "v5"
        },
        {
            "key": "k3",
            "value": "v6"
        }
    ]
]
itemcount = 0

for item in json_array:
    print(item)
    values = []
    
    for kv in item:
        if 'value' in kv:
                values.append(kv['value'])

    print(', '.join([kv['key']] + values))
```

Output:

```
[{'key': 'k1', 'value': 'v1'}, {'key': 'k1', 'value': 'v2'}]
k1, v1, v2
[{'key': 'k1', 'value': 'v3'}, {'key': 'k2', 'value': 'v4'}]
k2, v3, v4
[{'key': 'k2', 'value': 'v5'}, {'key': 'k3', 'value': 'v6'}]
k3, v5, v6
```

Expected output:

```
k1, v1, v2, v3
k2, v4, v5
k3, v6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
json_array = [
    {
        "key": "k1",
        "value": "v1"
    },
    {
        "key": "k2",
        "value": "v2"
    }
]

itemcount = 0
values = []

for item in json_array:
    print(f'Item => {itemcount}')
    itemcount += 1
    
    if 'value' in item:
            print(f"Value => {item['value']}")
            values.append(item['value'])

print(', '.join(values))
```

That'll give you output like this:

```
Item => 0
Value => v1
Item => 1
Value => v2
v1, v2
```

If you just wanted `v1, v2` as the output, you could just do this:

```
values = []

for item in json_array:
    if 'value' in item:
            values.append(item['value'])

print(', '.join(values))
```

**What are we doing here?**

We loop through each item in the list. Each item is a dictionary. We ask the dictionary if it has 'value' property. If it has, then we add it to a list.

Finally, we join the list with ', ' separator.

You can morph this to whatever output you desire. Hope this gets you started.

---

## EDIT

## What if you have an nested lists/arrays?

```
json_array = [
    [
        {
            "key": "k1",
            "value": "v1"
        },
        {
            "key": "k2",
            "value": "v2"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "key": "k1",
            "value": "v3"
        },
        {
            "key": "k2",
            "value": "v4"
        }
    ]
]
itemcount = 0
values = []

for item in json_array:
    print(f'Item => {itemcount}')
    itemcount += 1
    
    for kv in item:
        if 'value' in kv:
                print(f"Value => {kv['value']}")
                values.append(kv['value'])

print(', '.join(values))
```

The result will be:

```
Item => 0
Value => v1
Value => v2
Item => 1
Value => v3
Value => v4
v1, v2, v3, v4
```

---

## EDIT 2

## If you want v1, v2 in one line and v3, v4 in another line

You could use a slightly modified code to print v1, v2 in one line and v3, v4 in another line.

```
json_array = [
    [
        {
            "key": "k1",
            "value": "v1"
        },
        {
            "key": "k2",
            "value": "v2"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "key": "k1",
            "value": "v3"
        },
        {
            "key": "k2",
            "value": "v4"
        }
    ]
]
itemcount = 0

for item in json_array:
    print(f'Item => {itemcount}')
    itemcount += 1
    
    values = []
    
    for kv in item:
        if 'value' in kv:
                print(f"Value => {kv['value']}")
                values.append(kv['value'])

    print(', '.join(values))
```

The result will be:

```
Item => 0
Value => v1
Value => v2
v1, v2
Item => 1
Value => v3
Value => v4
v3, v4
```

It seems like OP has figured this out already; great job.

---

## EDIT 3

## What if we want key, value1, value2, ...?

```
json_array = [
    [
        {
            "key": "k1",
            "value": "v1"
        },
        {
            "key": "k1",
            "value": "v2"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "key": "k1",
            "value": "v3"
        },
        {
            "key": "k2",
            "value": "v4"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "key": "k2",
            "value": "v5"
        },
        {
            "key": "k3",
            "value": "v6"
        }
    ]
]
itemcount = 0
values = {}

for item in json_array:
    itemcount += 1
    
    for kv in item:
        if kv['key'] not in values:
            values[kv['key']] = []
        
        values[kv['key']].append(kv['value'])
        
for key in values:
    print(key + ', ' + ', '.join(values[key]))
```

will result in:

```
k1, v1, v2, v3
k2, v4, v5
k3, v6
```

Comment: I seem to have an array of arrays. So this does not work in that case.

Comment: @deadshotpro I have added an example of array of arrays.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I am looking for something like v1,v2 <linebreak> v3,v4 <linebreak>, and so on...That is just 2 entries on one line.

Comment: @deadshotpro you probably figured it out already. I have added code to display how you wanted. You could further remove `print(f'Item => {itemcount}')` and `print(f"Value => {kv['value']}")` to see only the values printed out.

Comment: Thank you so much @zedfoxus. Much appreciated. I managed to implement it. As a tip could you tell me how to group the values based on common keys?

For ex:
json_array = [
    [
        {
            "key": "k1",
            "value": "v1"
        },
        {
            "key": "k1",
            "value": "v2"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "key": "k2",
            "value": "v3"
        },
        {
            "key": "k2",
            "value": "v4"
        }
    ]
]

How do I group it like; 
k1, v1, v2

Comment: Oh yeah, that is a simple one: Change `print(', '.join(values))` to `print(', '.join([kv['key']] + values))`. The [kv['key']] creates an array like ['k1']. I add this to values array to create ['k1', 'v1', 'v2']. Then, I join them with `', '` and bam...you have k1, v1, v2. Give it a try.

Comment: I just tried that but it doesn't work. I need the values of common keys to append in the same array. For, if k1 is the repeating key then related values like v1 will append to the array. The same will happen for other values like v2 which has the same key k1.

Comment: Check my edited code, output, and expected output in the question.

Comment: @deadshotpro Edit 3 added.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @zedfoxus. This really helps. I'll get back if I get stuck again. Thanks again.

Comment: @deadshotpro if you get stuck, you might have to open a new question. When you open a new question, you are very welcome to tag me in a comment, or comment here with a link to your question.